# Using underscore.js "debounce" function with typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, typescript

The basic idea is to prevent double clicks. I'm using html `<button>` to call a function when clicked, which makes an ajax call. Native `<button>` behaviour is prevented with `event.preventDefault()`, that means no form should be submitted. Also, i'm using TypeScript:

```
private form: JQuery;
...
private getTargetAndCallAjax(): void {
    var target: string = this.form.find("form").data("target");
    this.form.find("button[type='submit']").on("click", (event)=> {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.callAjax(target);
    });
}

private callAjax(target: string): void {
    ...
}
```

As , i've implemented `_.debounce` as:

```
private form: JQuery;
...
private getTargetAndCallAjax(): void {
    var target: string = this.form.find("form").data("target");
    this.form.find("button[type='submit']").on("click", (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
       var ajaxCall = function () { this.callAjax(target) };
       _.debounce(ajaxCall, 1000, true);
    });
}

private callAjax(target: string): void {
    ...
}
```

The goal is to call `this.ajaxCall(target)` every 1 second, if multiple `<button>` clicks detected. Unfortunately, function `this.ajaxCall(target)` gets never called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is becuase you have the wrong `this` context in `ajaxCall`. Fix:

```
var ajaxCall = () => { this.callAjax(target) };
```

PS: why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Additionally `_.debounce` *returns* a debounced *function* that you need to call. So the complete code:

```
   var debouncedAjaxCall = _.debounce(() => this.callAjax(target), 1000, true);
   debouncedAjaxCall();
```

Comment: it did not help - `this.callAjax(target)` is not called

Comment: if user click multiple times then call go multiple times, how can I handle this